# Drop down list can't stay on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, dropdown

i made my drop down list when i mouse hover on it's  appear as i want but if i drag mouse to list item it cant stays it disappear whenever  i try to select the list item by mouse over on list item i tried a lot but it solve by me.

```css
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    height:100vh;
    background:#d936c6;
}
.dropdown{/*styling the dropdown container*/
    height:10vh;
    background:#fff;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    margin:auto;    
}
.project{
    position:relative;
}
.project ul{/* styling ul o*/
    position:absolute;
    background:#520348;
    margin-top:10px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    list-style:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    opacity:0;
    pointer-event:none;
    transform:translateY(-10px);
    transition:all 0.4s ease;

}
.project a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;

}
.dropdown button{
    background:none;
    border:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:18px;

}
.dropdown button:hover{
    background:rgb(224,224,224);

}
.project li{
    background:#5e2e58;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;

}
.project li{
    background:#b581ae; 
}
.project button:hover + ul{
    opacity:1;
    transform:translateY(0px);
    pointer-event:all;

}
.project li:hover{
    background:#5e2e58;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;

}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="project">
    <button>Project</button>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Weather app</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Weather app</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Weather app</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Weather app</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Weather app</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

i made my drop down list when i mouse hover on it's  appear as i want but if i drag mouse to list item it cant stays it disappear whenever  i try to select the list item by mouse over on list item i tried a lot but it solve by me.

Comment: Hi, have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to refactor your HTML a bit.  The issue is that your CSS dictates the dropdown UL will be show when the button is hovered.  As soon as you move your mouse off of the button, the UL disappears.

CSS Tricks has a great write-up on CSS only dropdown menus: 
https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need to add `ul:hover,` to `.project button:hover + ul{`

working snippet:

```css
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    height:100vh;
    background:#d936c6;
}
.dropdown{/*styling the dropdown container*/
    height:10vh;
    background:#fff;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    margin:auto;    
}
.project{
    position:relative;
}
.project ul{/* styling ul o*/
    position:absolute;
    background:#520348;
    margin-top:10px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    list-style:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    opacity:0;
    pointer-event:none;
    transform:translateY(-10px);
    transition:all 0.4s ease;

}
.project a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;

}
.dropdown button{
    background:none;
    border:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:18px;

}
.dropdown button:hover{
    background:rgb(224,224,224);

}
.project li{
    background:#5e2e58;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;

}
.project li{
    background:#b581ae; 
}
ul:hover, /* added */
.project button:hover + ul{
    opacity:1;
    transform:translateY(0px);
    pointer-event:all;
}
.project li:hover{
    background:#5e2e58;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;

}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="project">
    <button>Project</button>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Weather app</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Weather app</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Weather app</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Weather app</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Weather app</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```